# Merge sort - errors in code

Tags: c, sorting

I wrote a short code that receives an array and sorts it.
This was my first time and I have so many error - please if you can
explain to me how to fix and where/what are my mistakes...
All I want to do is to sort the array and print it after sorting.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int merge_sort(int *a,int first, int last)
{
    int middle;
    if(first < last)
    {
        middle=(first+last)/2;
        merge_sort(a,first,middle);
        merge_sort(a,middle+1,last);
        merge(a,first,middle,last);
    {
}

void main()
{
    int x[] = {1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 0, 6};
    int xsize= (sizeof x / sizeof x[0])
    merge_sort(x, 0, sizeof x / sizeof x[0]);

    for (int i = 0; i < xsize; i++) { printf("%d ", x[i]); } putchar('\n');
}
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the line that declares `xsize` for one thing, and you haven't defined `merge`, and `main` returns `int`, not `void`. Also, write your `for` loop normally

Comment: You also haven't told us what errors. Some are obvious, but you've got to give us information if you want help.

Comment: "i have so many error" ... such as?

Comment: The `{` after the `merge` call should be a `}` (and should that be a call to `merge_sort()`?).  That probably gets you past the worst of the compilation errors - you can then get on with fixing the other problems (there are a number of them).

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the line that declares xsize for one thing? sorry can you please explain or show me i dont know what you mean

Comment: `int xsize = (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]);` - and use `xsize` in the call to `merge_sort()` as well as in the `for` loop.

Comment: Alexxx, you should really start with the basics of learning `C`, and how to read compiler errors. Even some basic syntax is wrong here. Semicolon after every statement. You've got a backwards curly brace. Go read up and learn the basics!

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < xsize; i++) { printf("%d ", x[i]); } putchar('\n');` would be the more conventional way of writing the loop.  The braces are optional (I'd omit them in the code, but used them in the comment here for clarity).  Note that you should ensure that there is a newline at the end of the output.

Comment: @Bernard I cannot imagine that it's not homework.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: s/semicolon/curly brace/ (fixed)

Comment: You only ever have one error at most.  The first one.  Fix the first one.

Comment: `void main()` is not valid C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see multiple errors in your program

1. `int xsize= (sizeof x / sizeof x[0])` must have a semicolon `;` at the end.
2. `for(int i=0;i<xsize;printf("%d ",x[i]), i++);` is not the way to print the elements of the array.
3. your `merge()` is missing - `merge(a,first,middle,last);`

So I went ahead and wrote this sample `mergesort` for your reference. Hope this helps!!

```
#include <stdio.h>

/*

NOTE: 
The mergesort boils downs to this.. 
Given two sorted array's how do we merge this?

We need a new array to hold the result of merging
otherwise it is not possible to do it using array, 
so we may need a linked list

*/

void merge(int a[], int i, int j)
{
    int mid = (i+j)/2;
    int ai = i;
    int bi = mid+1;

    int newa[j-i+1], newai = 0;

    while(ai <= mid && bi <= j) {
        if (a[ai] > a[bi])
            newa[newai++] = a[bi++];
        else                    
            newa[newai++] = a[ai++];
    }

    while(ai <= mid) {
        newa[newai++] = a[ai++];
    }

    while(bi <= j) {
        newa[newai++] = a[bi++];
    }

    for (ai = 0; ai < (j-i+1) ; ai++)
        a[i+ai] = newa[ai];

}

void mergesort(int a[], int i, int j)
{
    int mid = (i+j) / 2;

    if (i >= j) return;

    mergesort(a, i, mid);
    mergesort(a, mid+1, j);
    merge(a, i, j);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    //int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
    int a[] = {9, 7, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1, 8, 6, 10};
    int i;

    mergesort(a, 0, 9);

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf ("%d ", a[i]);

    printf ("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you - i have learned a lot from you example - now i understand my mistakes

Comment: @Alexxx If you find my answer satisfying, please confirm the same by clicking the tick mark next to it! .. I'm glad it helped you! Thanks!

Comment: @Alexxx could you please share the error?!